# Nautilus don't change to dark mode

Tags: nautilus, themes

I'm using ubuntu 23.04, I used both chrome & firefox, but when uploading / downloading files, nautilus showing the light theme, even when the system use dark mode. Anyone having same problem?

Thank you
[preview of the nautilus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT39u.png)

Comment: What you see when uploading or downloading files is not nautilus, but a GTK4 file dialog. The issue is there with applications installed as a snap. Did you already restart (or logout/log in) after setting the theme to dark? If not, it may work after that.

Comment: I did restart but nothing happened. This also happened on chrome (flatpak). Any ideas what might be the issue? Thank you!

Comment: anyone pls help