# Nautilus "Save as..." from browser download appears white while the theme is yaru-dark-red everywhere after 22.04 to to 22.10 to 23.04 update

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes

a couple hours ago i was running ubuntu 22.04 LTS and wanted to switch to the latest release, so i've updated via terminal to 22.10 and then to 23.04, everything looks fine, but when i press "save as" on ANY of the browsers i've tried (chrome, new edge, firefox) nautilus appears white while my main theme is yaru-dark-red! i've tried using both these terminal codes:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-yaru-red-dark`
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-yaru-dark`

but it still appears white when i try to save any file (and it literally melts my eyeballs on a 28" monitor) is there any fix? or somewhere i can try to tinker? even trying to dig using `dconf-editor` didn't help cause there wasn't any useful toggle there ^^"

**last night i was on discord with a friend of mine who has linux too, told him about my problem and this morning he sent me these messages, hope someone can find them helpful to find a solution ^^"**

Created a new VM in Gnome-Boxes for Ubuntu LTS 20.4
Changed to dark mode in gnome-control-center
Nautilus is is dark mode as well as when saving from Firefox
Nautilus is installed to the system, Firefox is in a snap
Opted for pre-released updates and upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10, opting 'yes' any time asked
Nautilus and saving from Firefox still in dark mode
Upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04, opting 'yes' any time asked
Nautilus is still in dark mode while saving from Firefox is light mode
I was able to replicate the issue. I'll see if I can fix it

Tried changing system theme to light and back to dark - no change
Changed Firefox themes - no change
Restarted snapd-desktop-integration - no change
Installed Microsoft Edge from .deb
Same issue
Installed gnome-tweaks
Installed and changed to a new dark theme - no change
Gnome version 44.0
Tried to create a VM for GNOME OS Nightly but kept failing either through .iso or automatically through Boxes

It's something with Gnome/Ubuntu's fork of Gnome
I'm on Gnome 44 on Arch myself and don't see the issue

Comment: Same question here : https://askubuntu.com/q/1465019/558158 This is happening with applications installed as snap

Comment: @vanadium thanks for the answer but the issue is not related to snap installs, my firefox is snap installed, my chrome is from a .deb and my new edge is installed through apt, all those have the same issue

Comment: Has to do with GTK3 and support for it. Calculator is likely white too as it does not support GTK3. The save as and settings options in browsers is white too it needs a bug fix. Unlikely you will find a fix from us here.

Comment: @Rinzwind i've just tried to open the calculator and for me it's black, now i'm getting more confused

Comment: My calculator white whatever I do using the new cinnamon. There are a few more things white It is all related to the support of gtk3 for the program used. doubt we can fix it and it is likely to get a bug fix.